# confused about nodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I don't know if this question has it right place in `SO`, if not tell m , I will move it.

I am used to `Rails` and I am interested by `nodeJS` and I would like to understand what `non blocking` connections mean.

Does this mean that there is a persistent connection to `database` ? (explicitly is `socket.io` providing that ?) If there are great number of persistent connections, how can a server treat them ?

Btw, I read that `nodeJS` doesn't need the return value of the database to complete the treatment of a function, which speeds up the processing. Is that right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non blocking refers to I/O like accessing files on a hard drive, querying a database.  If you've every used something like jQuery think of it like this:

```
$.post('file.php', function (results) {
    // do something with 'results', which was sent back to use from 'file.php'
    console.log("Results returned...");
}, "json");

console.log ("End!");
```

Now on the client side, javascript will make this POST request, but it won't wait for it to return the results.  Console will output "End!" before it outputs "Results returned...".  Node is a lot like that.  You pass a lot of anonymous functions as callbacks to then respond.  Here's a database example (node-mysql):

```
connection.query('SELECT * FROM table1', function(error, rows) {
    if( error ) throw error;

    // do something with rows (an array)
});
```

The 'function( error, rows )'  passed to the connection.query method will be called once the query has finished.  And just like the jQuery $.post example above, it won't stop and wait.  This allows node to do other things in the meantime.

I hope I explained it well enough.  I used to dislike javascript, jQuery cured me of that, and now node is all I dream of. :D

Comment: And as for sockets, think of that as more of event driven.

Comment: Thank you, but the behavior you describe are they strictly related to `javascript` ? or can you mimic that with other languages ?

Comment: user1611830: Javascript is very well suited for this with its functions that behave just as variables that can be passed around as callbacks very easily. However, it is possible to write async, non-blocking code in most languages. For example modern .NET libraries make heavy use of it.

Comment: @Ineentho ok interesting ! you mean that `nodeJS` has no structural advantage on other language that can't be beaten ?

Comment: The big advantage with node.js is that it is practically forcing you to write non-blocking code. If you would write blocking code in node.js the whole application would freeze, while in other languages you could just start new threads to solve the problem. I belvie nodes approch will be the winning for server applications.

Comment: It all depends on what your project is.  I wouldn't use node to say...find prime numbers, but to send out html pages, heck yes, it's very fast and can handle a lot of requests.  Again, depends on what you want to do, from there you can pick the language that best suits it.  Node is also nice because you won't have to switch between javascript on the client side, and php (for example) on the server side.